# How to control scale invariance?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

I am trying to put several diagrams together in a kind of a table. I think this is called *"index
print"*, photography people do that when they have to review many photographs at once. Anyway,
this is the code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = mainWith @(Diagram B)
     $ (tile . fmap renderOne) examples

renderOne :: AnyGraph -> Diagram B
renderOne (AnyGraph gr) = ...

tile :: [Diagram B] -> Diagram B
tile xs = let columns = (ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral . length) xs
          in (vcat . fmap hcat . List.chunksOf columns) xs
```

It does not work as I expect. But let us approach it gradually. First, here is a render of a
single tile:

[image: one]

Now, let us `hcat` four tiles together.

[image: hcat]

Add a second row: *(See how [scale invariant](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html#scale-invariance) features thicken.)*

[image: tile2]

And this is how it looks with 4 rows:

[image: tile]

Out of hand!

It seems to me that scale invariant features, such as arrow heads, are scaled in proportion to the *area* of the picture. But in this case, I need to grow my diagram without re-scaling those features. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [user manual section on measurement units](https://diagrams.github.io/doc/manual.html#measurement-units) is what you want to look at.  Things like arrowheads are by default measured in "normalized" units, which are scaled so that they are always a constant proportion of the size of the whole picture.  If I understand your use case correctly, I think you probably want to use local units instead.  Use the primed variant of whatever arrow function you are using, and give it an options record something like

```
(with & headLength .~ local 0.1)
```

but with whatever number makes your pictures look the way you want.  See the [arrow tutorial](https://diagrams.github.io/doc/arrow.html#arrowopts) for more on arrow options.